# Disappearing Command Prompt VB Script

Tags: vb.net

Problem: Simple GUI with a button which triggers a batch file to run via cmd. Works for simple and fast scripts (ie `mkdir foo`), but more advanced scripts which need time to finish, it fails. The problem seems to surround cmd closing before the script can finish. I have included a `WaitForExit()` clause, but it seems to be ignored.

```
Private Sub RunButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RunButton.Click
    Dim foo as String = IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "Foo\Scripts\foo.bat")
    Dim p As New Process
    Application.DoEvents()
    p.StartInfo.FileName = foo
    p.Start()
    p.WaitForExit()
End Sub
```

Any ideas how to correct this issue? I see lots of posts about `WScript` and creating a shell object; do I really need to do it like that? This process seems to work, but it just closes out before the process finishes.

Comment: I don't think that it should matter but if you get rid of all but the first line and add `Process.Start(foo).WaitForExit()` do you see the same behaviour? If so, are you ABSOLUTELY sure that it's not the script failing? You're not setting the working directory so could that be an issue?

Comment: Same result. The script runs fine in cmd and powershell. Working directory issue is interesting; I'll report back. Thanks

Comment: While you're there, remove that `Application.DoEvents()`. You can also start cmd.exe with `/k` or `start /WAIT` and see what happens in the Console window when you start the command (e.g., `FileName = "cmd.exe"` and `Arguments = "/C START /b /WAIT foo.bat"`)

Comment: Seems odd that this would be killing off the process without completing.  Are you 100% sure that it's not the bat file that is erroring.  I know you can run it fine via PowerShell, but perhaps there are some environmental limits when running via VS your hitting.  Maybe update your question with an example bat that's not working?

Comment: @Hursey, this seems to be the issue. I've got the script finally running, now I cannot get the arguments passing to it properly. I think this one is solved, but I will probably start a new question for my argument issue.